# How do I prevent orders from being displayed repeatedly on the checkout screen when selecting multiple times

Tags: django, python-3.x

For my store, I basically have a quantity box with an add item option. When I select the quantity and click on the add item, the order gets added to my list of orders and it is displayed on checkout. However, Suppose  I Select Order A for the first time and set quantity as 5. The second time, I selected Order A again and set quantity as 3, I want it to add to the previous order and display quantity as 8. However, in case of my code, it displays it as separate orders. How do I solve this issue?

## views.py

```
def addItem(request):
   selected_supply = Supply.objects.get(pk=request.POST['supplyID'])
   qty = request.POST['qty']
   try:
       current_order = Order.objects.filter(owner=1).get(status="pre-place")
   except Order.DoesNotExist:
       current_order = Order.objects.create(owner=Manager.objects.get(pk=1), status="pre-place")
   order_detail = OrderDetail.objects.create(orderID=current_order, supplyID=selected_supply, quantity=qty)
   return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Store:browse'))
```

## models.py

```
class OrderDetail(models.Model): #change to orderitem
    orderID = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    supplyID = models.ForeignKey(Supply, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.orderID.pk}: {self.supplyID.name}  {self.quantity}'

class Order(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(ClinicManager, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2,  default=0.00)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    placeTime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    dispatchTime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    deliveredTime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.pk}'
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if (self.priority == other.priority):
            return self.placeTime < other.placeTime
        elif (self.priority == "High"):
            return True
        elif (other.priority == "Low"):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Comment: What's `OrderDetail` and `Supply` in this? You only talk about `Order` in your description. Please be more specific about what's happening, and what result you're expecting in terms of the objects you use in your view. Rephrase your own question rather than adding details in the comments.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to add the models/ Order detail contains the order ID supply ID and quantity. My order consists of the owner, weight, status, priority, dispatch time etc

Comment: "I select Order A" doesn't make sense looking at your view, since the `Order` object isn't determined by any selection (you don't use `request.POST` parameter to select an `Order`).

Comment: updated with models

Comment: "it displays it as separate orders." doesn't make sense either since you're not creating a new`Order`... Please rephrase the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are finding hard here. You already know how to get an existing item and update it, as you do it with Order. Why can't you do the same thing with OrderDetail: find any existing OrderDetail for that order with that supplyId and update its quantity, or if it doesn't exist create a new one.